# Unity: Drag & Drop script doesn't work on my prefab gameobject but DOES work on regular UI gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag, drop

I have a simple script that works just fine on any normal UI objects like an image.

But it doesn't work at all for my prefab gameobject, why is that?
I have attached a whole bunch of components to try out, like images, canvas renderer and all kinds, nothing works for me. I can also only SEE the damn prefab when I run the game, I can't see it on the Game tab. I have no clue. This is so strange.

Anyways, If I didn't make myself clear, please let me know what I need to explain or include for anyone to give me an answer?

```
public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
   public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("onBegindrag");
    }


    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.transform.position = eventData.position;
        Debug.Log("ondrag");
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("onEndDrag");
    }
}
```

Does this script only work on UI things? If so, Can I add a component to my prefab so that it is a UI item? Im working in 2d.

Answer (score 2):

By default these primerily **UI** events are only casted onto UI elements (`Image`, `Text`, etc) which have `Raycast Target` enabled (using the `GraphicsRaycaster` component attached to the according `Canvas`).

If you want to be able to also use them on "normal" 3D objects you need

- An `EventSystem` in your scene (already the case otherwise it wouldn't work for UI either)
- `Collider` components on your objects
- A [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-PhysicsRaycaster.html) component on your `Camera`!

For some reason I don't know this is only mentioned in the [`IPointerClickHandler (Unity 2019.1 and older)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) but afaik this still applies to all the `EventSystem`-related events / interfaces.